# How to import Xbee to Python?

Tags: networking, python, hardware, xbee

I would like to handle my xbee with raspberry pi via Python.
I install xbee with this command:

```
pip install xbee
```

And I try to use this example code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# Import and init an XBee device
from xbee import XBee,ZigBee
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

# Use an XBee 802.15.4 device
# To use with an XBee ZigBee device, replace with:
#xbee = ZigBee(ser)
xbee = XBee(ser)

# Set remote DIO pin 2 to low (mode 4)
xbee.remote_at(
  dest_addr='\x56\x78',
  command='D2',
  parameter='\x04')

xbee.remote_at(
  dest_addr='\x56\x78',
  command='WR')
```

This code is from this site: [Python xbee](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee)

When I try to execute this code I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Xbee
```

When I type this command:

```
pip search xbee
```

I see the Xbee module:

```
egenix-mx-base            - eGenix mx Base Distribution for Python -
                            mxDateTime, mxTextTools, mxProxy, mxTools,
                            mxBeeBase, mxStack, mxQueue, mxURL, mxUID
XBee                      - Python tools for working with XBee radios
  INSTALLED: 2.1.0 (latest)
hachi                     - XBee API
txXBee                    - XBee Protocol for Twisted
pyctu                     - A curses interface to configure xbees
```

What am I doing wrong? How to import the xbee module to python?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your error message, "ImportError: cannot import name Xbee", it looks like you might have typed "from xbee import Xbee" and not "from xbee import XBee".

Comment: Nicely spotted! @David Always keep in mind that python (and many other scripting and programming languages) are case sensitive, thus Xbee and XBee are two different things.

Comment: Couldn't resist it: you mean to say 'Xbee or not XBee: that is the question....' ? ;-)